# setting \tabskip in a repeating \halign preamble

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Is it somehow possible to set the `\tabskip` glue to zero for the first and last column in a repeated `\halign`?

Eg.

```
% tabskip=0pt
\halign{&#\hfil\tabskip1em plus1em minus.5em\cr
  Foo&Bar&Baz\cr
  \noalign{\smallskip\hrule}
}
\bye
```

There you can see that for the last column, there is a tabskip after it.

I would like to have a preamble which has zero tabskip for the first and last column. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve what you wish by doubling the number of columns.

```
\halign{&#\tabskip0pt&#\hfil\tabskip1em plus1em minus.5em\cr
  Foo&&Bar&&Baz\cr
  \noalign{\smallskip\hrule}
}
```

If the alignment is large, and you don't want to type `&` each time, it is possible to hide the extra `&` in the preamble and place it just after every `&` with `\aftergroup`. However, it needs to be removed after each `\cr`, hence the setting of `\everycr`. This, in turn, requires us to add a weird extra `\amp` after the first `\cr`.

```
\def\amp{&}
\begingroup
  \def\gobbleamp\amp{} \everycr{\gobbleamp}
  \halign{&#\tabskip0pt\aftergroup\amp&#\hfil\tabskip1em plus1em minus.5em\cr\amp
    Foo&Bar&Baz\cr
    \noalign{\smallskip\hrule}
  }
\endgroup
```

Ha! I got some "eviler" method, with a nicer input.

```
\def\amp{&}
\halign{&#\tabskip0pt&\amp#\hfil\tabskip1emplus1emminus.5em\cr
  Foo&Bar&Baz\cr
  \noalign{\smallskip\hrule}
}
```

The `\amp` is adding a `&` just after each `&` actually typed by the user.

TeX calls the part of a cell's preamble before `#` the "u-part", and the part after `#` the "v-part". Here, the `\amp` is in the u-part of the preamble for even cells. When such a cell starts, TeX expands the tokens to check for the presence of `\omit`. Once it sees (in our case) that there is no `\omit`, TeX inserts the u-part, hence an `\amp`. It then proceeeds with typesetting. `\amp` is expanded to `&`, which ends the cell. At this point, the v-part is inserted (`\hfil`). Then TeX starts the following odd cell after the `&` that the preamble had inserted.

Earlier, I was trying to put `\amp` in the v-part of the preamble for odd cells, naively equivalent: trying to insert `&` before each user-provided `&` instead of after. I don't fully understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: This is incredible wizardry.

Comment: @RyanReich: Thanks. You might prefer the new method I found (third code snippet) :D.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect not. From *TeX by Topic*

> The value of `\tabskip` that holds
>   outside the alignment is used before
>   the first column, and after all
>   subsequent columns, unless the
>   preamble contains assignments to
>   `\tabskip`. Any assignment to `\tabskip`
>   is executed while TeX is scanning the
>   preamble; the value that holds when
>   a tab character is reached will be
>   used at that place in each row, and
>   after all subsequent columns, unless
>   further assignments occur. The value
>   of `\tabskip` that holds when `\cr` is
>   reached is used after the last column.

Comment: I was hoping there would've been some `\unvbox`-based magical solution for this, but oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, another solution with a frame and multispan columns.

We need the following preamble:

```
% \tabskip = 0 pt
  \vrule #\strut \tabskip = 0 pt plus 1 fil
& \hfil #\hfil
& #\vrule \tabskip = 0 pt \cr
```

To get an infinite preamble (second part after `& &`):

```
  % \tabskip = 0 pt
    \vrule #\strut \tabskip = 0 pt plus 1 fil
  & \hfil #\hfil
  & #\vrule \tabskip = 0 pt
& & #\tabskip = 0 pt plus 1 fil  % same as first element without \strut and \vrule
  & \hfil #\hfil
  & #\vrule \tabskip = 0 pt \cr % ends with a \vrule and a 0 pt \tabskip
```

After reducing the preamble, we've got:

```
\tabskip = 0 pt
\everycr = {} % code executed after each \cr
\halign to \hsize { % preamble (here we are in vertical mode)
                    \vrule #\strut \tabskip = 0 pt plus 1 fil
                & & \hfil #\hfil
                  & #\vrule \tabskip = 0 pt % the table always ends with this column
                  & #\tabskip = 0 pt plus 1 fil \cr % same as first element without \strut and \vrule
        % body (here we are in vertical mode)
        \noalign { \hrule } % here we are in vertical mode
        & \multispan 7\hidewidth Just a table\hidewidth &\cr % 9 columns − first − last = 7 multispan
        \noalign { \hrule } % No space after the argument of multispan!
        & 2& & & 5& & & 8& \cr
        \noalign { \hrule }
        & \multispan 4\hidewidth multispan = 4\hidewidth & & & 8& \cr
        \noalign { \hrule } }
```

[image]

I use `\hidewidth …\hidewidth` instead of `\hfil …\hfil` to center, because the text to center (“Just a table”, “multispan = 4”) is “wide” (wider than expected by TeX so the table would be messy!)

Note: I don't usually use a framed table. (And I don't usually use a table at all! :))