# Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncdiag command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

The `pst-node` package provides the `\ncdiag` command, which allows you to connect two nodes with a diagonal line, but with an extra `arm` parameter which puts a bend in the line and allows the connections at each end to meet the node perpendicularly. Is there a simple way to get this effect in TikZ?

Here's an example (compile with latex or xelatex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\rput(0,3){\rnode{A}{Foo}}
\rput(2,0){\rnode{B}{Bar}}
\ncdiag[angleA=-90,angleB=90,arm=5mm]{A}{B}
\hspace{2in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (A) {Bar};
\node at (-2,3) (B) {Foo};
\draw[thick] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: You can specify the arm lengths individually as `armA=<len>` or `armB=<len>`, or both using `arm=<len>` (similar to specifying the angle for each individual node).

Comment: @Werner Yes, thanks.  I know how the `pstricks` command works; I'm really looking for how to do it in `tikz`, since I've mainly moved away from using `pstricks`, (although I used to use it a lot.)

Comment: why do you use the environment `pspicture`? It makes no sense, especially in your case without using coordinates

Comment: @Herbert It was there from a previous version of the document.  I've removed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Herbert: Why does `\rnode{}{\rput(){}}`  not work while `\rput(){\rnode{}{}}` works?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's my first shot.  I do it using a `to` path, which allows me to replace a path by something else.  The first bit of the arm is easy enough, but the second needs the `calc` library.  Also, when applied to nodes then the arm length is relative to the *centre* of the node, not the length of path that is actually drawn.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25474/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\tikzset{
  arm angleA/.initial={0},
  arm angleB/.initial={0},
  arm length/.initial={0mm},
  arm/.style={
    to path={%
      (\tikztostart) -- ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arm
         angleA}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arm length}) -- ($(\tikztotarget)+
         (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arm angleB}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arm length})$)
          -- (\tikztotarget)
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\rput(0,3){\rnode{A}{Foo}}
\rput(2,0){\rnode{B}{Bar}}
\ncdiag[angleA=-90,angleB=90,arm=5mm]{A}{B}
\hspace{2in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,3) (A) {Foo};
\node at (2,0) (B) {Bar};
\draw[thick] (A) to[arm, arm angleA=-90,arm angleB=90,arm length=5mm] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Note: I changed the node positions in the TikZ one to match the PSTricks specification.)

Picture, PSTricks on left, TikZ on right:

[image: tikz arm]

Comment: what you have is not the arm length, it is the distance from the node center, better seen with angleA=0. And by the way, to compare both delete the [br] and [tl] they make no sense, use [lb]

Comment: I guess to exactly match pstricks, you'd have to start from `A.angleA`, set `inner sep=0` and write a wrapper with `\tikzmark` and `[remember picture,overlay]`. However, I don't think the point of this question is to copy pstricks.

Comment: @Caramdir: Also, that would only work for nodes.  This works for any coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It needs further adjustments but I think this is also a valid yet quick and dirty solution. It can be embedded in a short function.

Also a minor detail about the positioning of the node : you might want to anchor the matrices because the absolute positioning of the text is not exactly aligned to the coordinates where I declare.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep = 2mm] (B) at (2,0) 
{
\node[inner sep=1mm] {}; \\
\node {Bar}; \\
};

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep = 2mm] (F) at (0,3) 
{
\node {Foo}; \\
\node[inner sep=1mm] {}; \\
};

\draw (B-2-1) -- (B-1-1.north) -- (F-2-1.south) -- (F-1-1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with the `row sep` to extend or shorten the arms.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

(quite old topic) A simple solution in TikZ is as follows. Notice that we can plus a node with a coordinate (as well as plus 2 nodes or 2 coordinate).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0) node (Foo) {Foo}
(2,-3) node (Bar) {Bar};

\draw (Foo)--++(-90:.5)--($(Bar)+(90:.5)$)--(Bar);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```