# Word alignment graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics

I am looking for a way to visualize word alignment between sentence pairs that would look like this:
[image]
(taken from https://aclanthology.org/W11-4615.pdf)

I've already come across [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25436/any-nice-packages-for-word-alignment)  but am not happy with the tikz solution, since it first puts the nodes in a matrix, which looks bad when there is a big difference in character length:
[image]

I tried using the PStricks snippet, but for some reason no lines are drawn (compiling with xelatex).

Before I approach the authors of that paper and ask for the source code, I thought I might ask here if anybody knows of a simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: See `tikzmark` library. For an example of its use see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619925/

Comment: For `pstricks`, how did you compile? You should use `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very light answer to your question but this is the spirit. `tikzmark` library is of great help doing that kind of thing. If you already know about Ti*k*Z, you can adjust whatever you want afterwards. You can see that not everything is perfectly aligned but it's the general idea.

[image: word alignment graph]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.style={inner sep = 1pt,execute at end node={\vphantom{bg}}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \tikzmarknode{HE}{He} \tikzmarknode{GAVE}{gave} \tikzmarknode{ME}{me} \tikzmarknode{THE}{the} \tikzmarknode{BOOK}{book}
        
        \vspace*{1cm}
        
        \tikzmarknode{HAN}{Han} \tikzmarknode{GAV}{gav} \tikzmarknode{BOKEN}{boken} \tikzmarknode{TILL}{till} \tikzmarknode{MIG}{mig}
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw   (HE) -- (HAN)
                (GAVE) -- (GAV)
                (ME.south) -- (TILL)
                (ME.south) -- (MIG)
                (THE) -- (BOKEN.north)
                (BOOK) -- (BOKEN.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!