# Create my own NSD

Tags: plain-tex

I'm trying to create a set of macro-s for plain [Xe]TeX to be able to create Nassi-Shneidermann Diagrams that produces a table (`\halign`). (I would note the cases slant lines differently in a way, that we can ignore it for this question.)

To create a table, I need to know the columns number of the final NSD, so I need to accumulate the commands. But if I accumulate the commands, I also have to put information that at the time I call a macro, I cannot know it, namely the number of columns.

So the question is, how can I make some sort of container, that can accumulate tokens, and when expanded with a parameter, it would put in the proper final result? For an example, if we ignore the borders of such diagram and I would like to put a command structure before an if-then-else structure in the diagram, it would produce a `\span\omit` pair in the command's cell, or with a 5 case structure, it would put 4 `\span\omit` macro pairs.

---

I don't know how I want it to be like in it's final stage but for an exact specific example, I want something like this:

```
\beginstruct
\command{i:=1}
\strutif i≠5
\then
j:=j-1
\else
SKIP
\strutfi
\endstruct
```

to yield something like this:

```
\halign{
&#\vrule&\hfil#\hfil\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
&i:=1\multispan2&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
&\char`\\\hfill i≠5\hfill/\multispan2&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
&j:=j-1&&SKIP&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
}
```

But if I only write:

```
\beginstruct
\command{i:=1}
\endstruct
```

would yield something like:

```
\halign{
&#\vrule&\hfil#\hfil\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
&i:=1&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
}
```

The problem here is that I need to know how that there is 2 collumns (excluding the borders) are there before I could write any number to `\multispan`. In my first example, the `\multispan` after `i:=1` have 2 as parameter, but it is not presents after the second example.

Comment: Can you elaborate with a specific example of you intend to you this macro. Otherwise it is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: As @Aditya says, a concrete example would help. Perhaps you could add the input syntax you want, and a graphic created in some way of what the result should be.

Comment: The part about `\omit\span` sounds a lot like `\multispan`

Comment: Also, could you use `\halign{&\vrule#&\hfil#\hfil\cr...}` ie. repeat?

Comment: The `\multispan` is a better solution, and generally the position of te `#` sign around `\vrule` is not interesting to me.

Comment: The `\halign{&` version seems OK. Can it repeats other then whole times?

Comment: Adam: sorry it took me this long, I didn't get notified of your comments. I expanded my comments in the form of an answer. I hope it helps!

Comment: I think that one would basically need 3 different "column types" for constructing a NSD-macro: 1) a normal block 2) a boolean block, and 3) a iteration block. 3) would need some serious wizardry in how to construct the `\halign`, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The TeX-language primitive for horizontal alignment, `\halign`, has preamble repeating properties which could perhaps be of use here. `\halign` sets the contents (if not told otherwise in the preamble) into `\hbox`es. Here are a couple of examples of its use:

```
\halign{&\ThisColumnGetsRepeated{#}\cr...}
```

The above preamble which starts off with an ampersand (`&`) repeats the column definition (`\ThisColumnGetsRepeated{#}`, *i.e.*, run the macro called `\ThisColumnGetsRepeated` for the given input) for every column repeatedly, so you can just give it (by replacing the dots above) endless amount of columns:

```
foo& bar& baz& foo& bar& baz& ... \cr
```

But what if you‘d want the first column (say) to have some special treatment while still repeating some other column *ad infinitum* later on? There‘s another form for that:

```
\halign{\SomethingDifferentForThisColumn{#}&&\ThisColumnGetsRepeated{#}\cr ...}
```

The column definitions after `&&` gets repeated.

Once you fall in love with `\halign`'s repeating capabilities, you could appreciate the possibility to turn off the `\tabskip` glue in them for the last column. Bruno Le Floch has found a wonderful piece of magic for just that in [his answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/setting-tabskip-in-a-repeating-halign-preamble/32358#32358).

---

The other question asked how to repeatedly call for a sequence `\omit\span`. It so happens that plain-tex format has a macro for precisely that, namely, `\multispan`. `\multispan` takes as argument the number of columns it ought to `\span`, so `\multispan3` spans three columns, while `\multispan{13}` spans thirteen columns.

---

For finding out what number to feed to `\multispan`, you could count the columns by typesetting the table twice; first time only to count the columns, although I bet it would be easier to count the input instead. Here I've done it the hard way:

```
\newcount\colcount
\newcount\maxcolcount
\long\def\maxcols#1{
  \global\maxcolcount=0
  \everycr={\noalign{\global\colcount=1}}
  \setbox0=\vbox{\halign{&##\ifnum\colcount>\maxcolcount
    \global\maxcolcount=\colcount\fi\global\advance\colcount by 1\cr#1\cr}}
  \the\maxcolcount}
\maxcols{&&\cr&&&\cr&&&&&&&\cr}
```

^Outputs: 8

Then I tried to reproduce a NSD from an image I found:

```
\newdimen\boxitspace\boxitspace=0pt
\long\def\boxit#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule\kern\boxitspace\vbox{%
  \kern\boxitspace\parindent0pt#1\kern\boxitspace}%
  \kern\boxitspace\vrule}\hrule}}
\offinterlineskip
\boxit{\vbox{\halign{\quad\vphantom{$\Big)$}$#$\hfil&&
  \vrule\quad\vphantom{$\Big)$}$#$\hfil\quad\cr
  a \gets 1 \cr
  \multispan3\hrulefill\cr
  b \gets 1 \cr
  \multispan3\hrulefill\cr
  do~while~a < 12 \hidewidth\cr
  \omit& \multispan2\hrulefill\cr
  \omit& b \gets a*a \cr
  \omit& \multispan2\hrulefill\cr
  \omit& output~a,b \hidewidth\cr
  \omit& \multispan2\hrulefill\cr
  \omit& if~b < 100 \cr
  \omit& \multispan2\hrulefill\cr
  \omit& T & F \cr
  \omit& \multispan2\hrulefill\cr
  \omit& a\gets a+1 & a\gets a+2 \cr}}}
\bye
```

It looks like this:
[image]

But putting all these together into a single macro is a little beyond the time I have available for right now. Maybe I'll get back to this at a later time.

Happy TeXing! `:-)`

Comment: Fascinating, thank you! Though I think I still need to know how can accumulate macros for later interpreting, as I will need some kind of counter for know the maximum size of the table, to give proper value to `\multispan`. (‘columns used by table’ - ‘columns used by item’ + 1)

Comment: I've updated the question with a second example, to further demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Well that is quite helpful! Your `\maxcolcount` will definitely do the trick! I still have trouble to catch how can I produce the table twice though. I'll take a look in it.